# Shred XML document in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, shred

I've started shredding my XML document in SQL Server but I'm stuck on how to get tback out. I can currently only get the 3 elements under `inventorymodelday` to each row. How do you go "back up" in levels so I can apply the `inventorymodel id` to each row (in this case "Default")?

```
SELECT
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('DemandPercent').value('.', 'float'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('StocksPerDay').value('.', 'int'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('Supply').value('.', 'int')
FROM(
    SELECT CAST(InvModels AS xml)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK '***.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(InvModels)
) AS T(InvModels)
CROSS APPLY InvModels.nodes('inventorymodels/inventorymodel/inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday') AS InvModels(inventorymodelday)
```

```
<inventorymodels count="1">
  <inventorymodel id="Default">
    <inventorymodeldays count="7">
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>15.0000009536743</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>10</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>1</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>11</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>12</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>13</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>19</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>1</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>1</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
      <inventorymodelday>
        <DemandPercent>20</DemandPercent>
        <StocksPerDay>0</StocksPerDay>
        <Supply>0</Supply>
      </inventorymodelday>
    </inventorymodeldays>
  </inventorymodel>
</inventorymodels>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that might work

```
SELECT
    InvModel.inventorymodel.value('@id', 'varchar(100)'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('DemandPercent').value('.', 'float'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('StocksPerDay').value('.', 'int'),
    InvModels.inventorymodelday.query('Supply').value('.', 'int')
FROM(
    SELECT CAST(InvModels AS xml)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK '***.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(InvModels)
) AS T(InvModels)
CROSS APPLY InvModels.nodes('inventorymodels/inventorymodel') AS InvModel(inventorymodel)
cross apply invModel.inventoryModel.nodes('inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday') as InvModels(inventorymodelday)
```

Comment: Please check the notable points in  my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *have* your XML in a variable `@input`, you could try this:

```
SELECT
    ModelId = xc.value('(../../@id)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
    DemandPercent = xc.value('(DemandPercent)[1]', 'decimal(25,15)'),
    StocksPerDay = xc.value('(StocksPerDay)[1]', 'int'),
    Supply = xc.value('(Supply)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/inventorymodels/inventorymodel/inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday') as XT(XC)
```

This will return a result like this:

| ModelId | DemandPercent | StocksPerDay | Supply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Default | 15.000000953674300 | 0 | 0 |
| Default | 10.000000000000000 | 0 | 1 |
| Default | 11.000000000000000 | 0 | 0 |
| Default | 12.000000000000000 | 0 | 0 |
| Default | 13.000000000000000 | 0 | 0 |
| Default | 19.000000000000000 | 1 | 1 |
| Default | 20.000000000000000 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to handle it via double **CROSS APPLY** clause that is simulating one-to-many relationship.

Notable points:

- No need to use `.query()` method. Just `.value()` method is enough.
- XPath `../text()` expression is used for performance reasons.

**SQL**

```
;WITH rs (xmldata) AS
(
    SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) AS BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\owneyjs.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)

SELECT c.value('@id', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS inventorymodel
    , x.value('(DemandPercent/text())[1]','FLOAT') AS DemandPercent
    , x.value('(StocksPerDay/text())[1]', 'INT') AS StocksPerDay
    , x.value('(Supply/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Supply
FROM rs
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/inventorymodels/inventorymodel') AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY t1.c.nodes('inventorymodeldays/inventorymodelday') AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----------------+------------------+--------------+--------+
| inventorymodel |  DemandPercent   | StocksPerDay | Supply |
+----------------+------------------+--------------+--------+
| Default        | 15.0000009536743 |            0 |      0 |
| Default        |               10 |            0 |      1 |
| Default        |               11 |            0 |      0 |
| Default        |               12 |            0 |      0 |
| Default        |               13 |            0 |      0 |
| Default        |               19 |            1 |      1 |
| Default        |               20 |            0 |      0 |
+----------------+------------------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: I got you by 10 seconds :)